Filter Formula Not Working to pull the correct rows
I am just a bit confused on why my formula isn't working for this filter function. Theoretically it should work but it doesn't seem to pull across the correct data but rather it is pulling across different data
Two Sources of Data
The last row on the left hand side "MRK24022" should be pulled across into the the right hand side but it is pulling the incorrect row. The formula below <>0 is just making sure that there is money for that particular month
TRUE Function
=FILTER(SORTBY('CR Potential'!$Z$5:$Z$1000,'CR Potential'!$AD$5:$AD$1000,1,'CR Potential'!$J$5:$J$1000,-1),'CR Potential'!$J$5:$J$1000<>0)
Not sure if anyone is able to make sense of this
Thanks
I have tried removing the SORTBY and using different columns to filter on but still nothing working

Can you share more details? What are you filtering? An Excel sheet? How is this problem related to programming?

I am not able to share the just because it is sensitive data, understand not much help can be given for cases like this

You can't share whether this related to Excel, Google Sheets, or something completely different?

Oh sorry, this is Excel based the formula I am using is =FILTER(SORTBY('CR Potential'!$Z$5:$Z$1000,'CR Potential'!$AD$5:$AD$1000,1,'CR Potential'!$J$5:$J$1000,-1),'CR Potential'!$J$5:$J$1000<>0)

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it
